# "Error putting S3 policy: Invalid Syntax"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to set up an S3 bucket policy in Terraform. I have written the following code in a module. The goal is to conditionally create the S3 bucket and the policy. The S3 bucket created just fine. However, I get this error for the aws_s3_bucket_policy. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket        = var.bucket
  bucket_prefix = var.bucket_prefix
  acl           = "log-delivery-write"
  count    = var.account != "" ? 1 : 0

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "AES256"
      }
    }
  }

  tags = {
    account = var.account
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0].id}"
  count    = var.account != "" ? 1 : 0
  
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Id" : "SSLPolicy",
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Sid" : "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
          "Action" : "s3:*",
          "Effect" : "Deny",
          "Resource" : [
            "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket[*].arn}",
            "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0].arn}/*",
          ],
          "Condition" : {
            "Bool" : {
              "aws:SecureTransport" : "false"
            }
          },
          "Principal" : "*"
        }
      ]
    }
  )

}
```

```
 Error: Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Invalid policy syntax.
│   status code: 400, request id: BN6FRWX8A6723GAP, host id: t3yhr16yMu7VOjLIdXup1O0SlDW062VLiYJXyZ5bR6+OwrP86wjzBe7iGNzIDzCqcB1H1WUn8Pk=
│ 
│   with module.test.aws_s3_bucket_policy.bucket[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/test/main.tf line 20, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket":
│   20: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
│
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aws_s3_bucket.bucket[*].arn` returns a **list** of arn values, not  the actual arn. Thus it should be:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "bucket" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0].id}"
  count    = var.account != "" ? 1 : 0
  
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Id" : "SSLPolicy",
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Sid" : "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
          "Action" : "s3:*",
          "Effect" : "Deny",
          "Resource" : [
            "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0].arn}",
            "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket[0].arn}/*",
          ],
          "Condition" : {
            "Bool" : {
              "aws:SecureTransport" : "false"
            }
          },
          "Principal" : "*"
        }
      ]
    }
  )

}
```